# Sleuth not sending trace information to Zipkin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

Sleuth is not sending the trace information to Zipkin, even though Zipkin is running fine.
I am using Spring 1.5.8.RELEASE, spring cloud Dalston.SR4 and I have added the below dependencies in my microservices:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My Logs are always coming false:
[FOOMS,2e740f33c26e286d,2e740f33c26e286d,false]

My Zipkin dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why am I getting false instead of true in my slueth statements? The traceId and SpanId are properly generated for all the calls though. My Zipkin is running in port 9411

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found that I need to add a sampler percentage. By default zero percentage of the samples are sent and that is why the sleuth was not sending anything to zipkin. when I added `spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0` in the properties files, it started working.

Comment: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.RELEASE/multi/multi__features_2.html in the `IMPORTANT` section it's written that:

> If using Zipkin, configure the percentage of spans exported using spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage (default 0.1, i.e. 10%). Otherwise you might think that Sleuth is not working cause it’s omitting some spans.

Comment: In recent version the key is changed to "spring.sleuth.sampler.probability".

Answer (score 13):

For the latest version of cloud dependencies `<version>Finchley.SR2</version>`
The correct property to send traces to zipkin is: `spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0`
Which has changed from percentage to probability.

Answer (score 2):

If you are exporting all the span data to Zipkin, sampler can be installed  by creating a bean definition in the Spring boot main class

```
  @Bean
  public Sampler defaultSampler() {
    return new AlwaysSampler();
  }
```