# Zipkins(in spring boot Application) is not storing all the trace id's when i am sending 10 request from an application to other application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using ZIPKINS for distributed tracing the problem is when I am trying to test ZIPKINS by sending 10 request at a time to that service from other service by using loop,  checked the UI for the logs of that, I had got only 2 logs i.e for first and last, I haven't received logs of the remaining requests. Can you help in figuring out what is the problem in that. Trace ids and span ids are generated for all the request, I am unable to see that logs for the same. Logs that are received:

> 2020-03-04 17:38:57.379 INFO [,7c8075c14691f988,43521ecc69b84d84,true] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0121, 2020-03-04 17:38:57.438 INFO [,7552e8c3d87d013a,89769451aafec094,false] –
>
> 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0122, 2020-03-04 17:38:57.519 INFO [,79f38c25211dfab8,49ea12575eab0bcf,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received –
>
> Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0123, 2020-03-04 17:38:57.626 INFO [,294da34664fac032,ad98ed1fbce485df,false] 10576 --- [io-8081-exec-10] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0124, 2020-03-04 17:38:57.879 INFO [,8763a2ca3d6dfc44,9871d046cd7eacf1,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0125, 2020-03-04 17:38:57.923 INFO [,be1e3a490e114e92,2435ee34d215459c,false] –
>
> 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0126, 2020-03-04 17:38:57.980 INFO [,21855ca20670de31,6213a3fdc0a23189,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0127, 2020-03-04 17:38:58.043 INFO [,4d9795e7d2dbf50c,21f83b3384381833,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl : Receive

Comment: Are you sure that there are 10 different traceId and spanId generated>

Comment: yes there are i had checked that in the logs

Comment: there are four attributes right [name,traceid,spanid,somethind (true/false)], Here only the records with true are getting stored rest are not stored can anybody know what that and how to rectify that

Comment: You already got the root cause. Would better if you also add all of those attribute valus.(specially true/false). Or some logs.. which are stored and which are ignored.

Comment: this are the logs-----2020-03-04 17:38:57.379  INFO [,7c8075c14691f988,43521ecc69b84d84,true] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0121, 
2020-03-04 17:38:57.438  INFO [,7552e8c3d87d013a,89769451aafec094,false]

Comment: 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0122, 
2020-03-04 17:38:57.519  INFO [,79f38c25211dfab8,49ea12575eab0bcf,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received

Comment: Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0123, 
2020-03-04 17:38:57.626  INFO [,294da34664fac032,ad98ed1fbce485df,false] 10576 --- [io-8081-exec-10] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0124, 
2020-03-04 17:38:57.879  INFO [,8763a2ca3d6dfc44,9871d046cd7eacf1,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0125, 
2020-03-04 17:38:57.923  INFO [,be1e3a490e114e92,2435ee34d215459c,false]

Comment: 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0126, 
2020-03-04 17:38:57.980  INFO [,21855ca20670de31,6213a3fdc0a23189,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received Message ='ServiceInvocation [communicationID=COMM_0127, 
2020-03-04 17:38:58.043  INFO [,4d9795e7d2dbf50c,21f83b3384381833,false] 10576 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] c.i.f.service.ProducerServiceImpl        : Received

Comment: Please don't add those in comment. Edit question and add those there...

Answer (score 0):

Log format is: **[application name, traceId, spanId, export]**

So the last value `true/false` [is actually the export value which means](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-sleuth-single-application):

> **Export** – This property is a boolean that indicates whether or not this log was exported to an aggregator like Zipkin. Zipkin is beyond the scope of this article but plays an important role in analyzing logs created by Sleuth.

As export values are false, zipkin is not receiving those values. That is expected behavior.

---

**Root Cause**: Some of the logs are exporting and some are not is because of sampler rate. Not all of the logs are meant to be sent. Anyway if you want all of the logs to be sampled try adding this property:

```
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
```

Reference: [sleuth-not-sending-trace-information-to-zipkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670883/sleuth-not-sending-trace-information-to-zipkin)

Comment: Is there a way that we can add our custom fields in the the log of hystrix for unique identification of the log since trace id is not related to anything. Like i want to add one id i.e communication by which when i want to check the status of an application i can directly query that from the Elastic since i am trying to send all logs to elastic.

Comment: are you using log4j/slf4j? Yes you can! That's a different question. Make a seperate question with your expectation and existing log4j*.xml file.